# Better than traceroute / nslookup

Tags: traceroute, nslookup

Im searching for a command that shows all IP addresses that you get in status bar when you connect to site.

Example: ebuddy.com, is not ony ebuddy.com, but
varnish.ebuddy.com
bsvc.ebuddy.com
web.ebuddy.com

and so on.
Does anyone know?

(Linux Mint, based on Ubuntu packages)

Answer (score 0):

Those are not IP addresses, but subdomains and **there is no easy way to find all subdomains associated with a site other than brute-forcing.**

If it helps: you can google for "site:ebuddy.com -inurl:www" to see *some* subdomains, but it is not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, you want a text field displaying the result of `dig +short -t a www.ebuddy.com`. Considering traceroute probes the path to a destination host and nslookup resolves DNS names and IP addresses, this command shows the destination of a domain or subdomain.

Although, you'll have to accept the case of multiple A records.

```
$dig +short -t a www.ebuddy.com
193.238.162.245
193.238.162.243
193.238.162.242
193.238.162.241
```

CNAME records may obfuscate the result.

```
$dig +short -t a web.ebuddy.com
www.ebuddy.com.
193.238.162.243
193.238.162.245
193.238.162.242
193.238.162.241
$
$
$
$dig +short -t cname web.ebuddy.com
www.ebuddy.com.
```

As **ntv1000** already mentioned, there is not way of finding out all subdomains. With the exception of AXFR. But that query is most certainly not available to the public.